# select all rows in gridview without paging

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a gridview with 100 Rows with paging turned on (showing 20 rows at a time).

There is a checkbox in each row to select that record.

In the header there is a "check all" checkbox

When I check it will just select the 20 from the current page.

Is there a way to have it select all 100 rows with out resizing the size of the page (have it show all 100 rows).

Thanks

Comment: You can have a property in that table which is bound to grid and you can set this attribute when checkall is clicked and based on this attribute the checkbox in each row can be rendered.

Comment: @Sridhar why a comment when you have an answer?

Comment: how do you bring the records from DB ?? 20 at a time or u bring all and display 20 ??

Answer (score 0):

Add a field checked in your datalist , and set its value according to the checked all checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

> You can have a property in that table which is bound to grid and you
>   can set this attribute when checkall is clicked and based on this
>   attribute the check box in each row can be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind any functionality on all the rows in gridview, you can simply use dataview of the data source of the grid view on check all click. Or you can perform desired operation on the datasource(data table or dataset) on CheckAll checkbox checked